# Django request deserialization

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to deserialize request.body:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
import json



def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.body) > 0 and len(request.FILES) == 0:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
```

And I am getting JSONDecodeError right at the last line. Python 3.6.4 (no need to decode, shoukd accept bytes), Django 2.0.7.
When I am trying to print out request.body I get:

```
b'username=1&password=1&email=and%40gm.co&csrfmiddlewaretoken=1iv975vw86CmmcDQM7IbpWxKsRn3J0RguI4ek5qKmTSfnyCRmu3wy7tcG0f36Cmr'
```

Also type(request) if that might help:

```
<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need load body with json? I quess that all you need is in `request.POST` object. Try to `print(request.POST)` somewhere

Comment: You're a saviour! Thank you so much!